# Using "this" as a parameter to copy constructor

Tags: c++

I have a c++ class, let's say it's called c, and I want to use the implicit copy constructor in one of the methods, like this:

```
c c::do_something() {
  c copy = this; //I want implicit copy constructor here!
  copy.something_else(); 
  //........//
  return copy;
}
```

However, gcc returns this error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'c* const' to 'long unsigned int'

(I have another constructor from long unsigned int present)

... as if the copy constructor didn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*this* is a pointer to an object so it should be

```
c copy = *this;
```

Comment: This is really using the default constructor and then the assignment operator, *not* the copy constructor. See Matt's response.

Comment: Andrew: I am not sure - Josh below (and some sites) says the opposite

Comment: @Andrew no, it uses the copy constructor.

Comment: A a = b; will actually never invoke the default ctor + the assignment operator. There are circumstances where more than just the copy ctor is invoked (eg cast operators), but you'll never get default ctor + assignment operator. See copy-initialization in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 9):

Quite an aside, but it won't really fit in a comment and there seems to be some disagreement.  Try this piece of code out to get an idea of when copy-constructors and assignment operators get called:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "A::A()\n"; }
    A(const A &) { cout << "A::A(const A &)\n"; }
    void operator =(const A &) { cout << "A::operator=(const A &)\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    A a; // default constructor
    A copy = a; // copy constructor (and no assignment operator)
    A copy2(a); // copy constructor (and no assignment operator)
    a = copy; // assignment operator
    A function(); // declares a function return A
    A b = A(); // default constructor (but no assignment operator)
    A b2 = A(a); // copy constructor (but no assignment operator)
}
```

Comment: For completeness it might be an idea to add a constructor "A(int)" and then show that "A a = 10;" is equivalent to: "A a(A(10))".

Answer (score 3):

Whoa whoa! Also, don't confuse the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator.

```
c copy (*this);
```

is the copy constructor;

```
c copy = *this;
```

is the copy assignment operator. Either will work, though the copy constructor is technically more efficient, though the copy assignment operator is often optimized to do the same thing.

---

Wow - I find myself corrected. Using the = operator in the same statement as the declaration of a variable does indeed call the copy constructor. You learn something new every day!

Comment: No - c copy(*this); is identical to c copy = *this; (provided that *this is of type c) both invoke the copy constructor.  c copy; copy = *this; invokes the default constructor and then the assignment operator.

Comment: It's not just a matter of efficiency... the copy constructor and assignment operator can be completely different functions.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the pointer of an object not the object himself.
You should use `*this` to get the object.